# Half-transparent object has dark shading on edges when using alpha blend

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, lighting, emission

[image: Example of dark edges around the cone]

Eevee, Blender 3.0

I'm attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTbXFH1a4BM) about making fake light cones, however when doing so there's a dark outline near the outer edge of the light. It doesn't show when using other blend modes, but I want to avoid the noise generated with alpha hashed as much as possible.

Here's the nodes I'm using currently:
[image: Node layout]

Example blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KyqWuM2JQewVCYakcBrIF8Q3bvcnbLdo/view

Comment: Perhaps clamp the math nodes.  At least the subtract.

Comment: Clamping the subtract did the trick! I also had to turn Show Backface on to get rid of a bit more.